# TASM moving data from different sources

Tags: assembly, tasm

I need a macro copy data from to:
Immediate operand (any size) to any register (include segments)
m8 to m8
m16 to m16
r8 to r8 (r8 - any register)

I thought, that it can be done with stack:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    var1 db 8h
    var2 db ?
    var3 dw 17h
.code
start:
    send macro param1,param2
        push param1
        pop param2
    endm send


send var1 var2
;exit
mov ah, 04ch
int 21h

end start
```

But I get error:
Argument to operation or instruction has illegal size

Comment: You should use the same sized registers. If you pop a 4 bytes long register over a byte you will overwrite 3 other bytes. You cannot use stack to save one byte sized variables unless you expand them into a word (e.g. movzcx).

Comment: Not sure how tasm works anymore, but try `send [var1] [var2]`. You might also need to specify operand size.

Comment: You don't need such macro. And you definitely don't want it either. (and if you need something so versatile, maybe you need to switch from assembly to some higher level language).

Comment: `var1` and `var2` are defined as `db`. You can't push a single byte on the stack so you end up TASM trying to produce this with the macro `push byte ptr [var1]` `pop byte ptr [var2]`. If you changed `var1` and `var2` to `dw` then it should work.

Comment: I need macro for different size of operands. I try using IF macro directive with type command, but TASM can't recognize pushw / pushb and popb / popw comands.

Comment: there's no good use for such macro in assembly, you are probably trying to do something in anti-assembly way. Maybe if you will ponder on TASM long enough, you will figure out some hack-ish way to achieve your macro, but that will just add more problems later. Like for example `send ss 0x2134` `send sp 0x5678` may sound like good idea of proper usage of such macro (to set up new stack), yet it will generate invalid machine code, damaging memory content randomly.